# GraphQL pagination limit parameter

Tags: graphql

How many rows should GraphQL query return when `limit = 0`, all rows or 0 rows ? Looks like this is not mentioned anywhere.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/results/

Comment: The API you reference is Facebook's "Graph API".  While Facebook is also a major contributor to GraphQL, and the cursor model appears in GraphQL in a Facebook-authored client library, that API is not actually GraphQL.